# Hand sanitizer and clean hands in halacha

Tags: halacha, cleaning

Is there any discussion among poskim about hand sanitizer as a replacement for any of the standard methods for washing one's hands in halacha? Can it be used solely, for example, after going to the toilet, in order to say the bracha or do we still need water/rubbing? Is it usable bedieved in any contexts where, say, washing with water is bedieved?

Comment: In terms of having clean hands, everything that cleans works, and hand sanitizers are wet so that should be fine. I don't see why it would replace netilas yadayim any more than a rock would (which also works for cleaning hands)

Comment: I would like to know if it is considered "as good as water" or "good enough when you don't have other options".

Comment: Some say any liquid is like water, but it must be fit for a dog’s drinking

Comment: But it’s probably good for Mayim Acharonim though

Comment: For washing for tefillah it would work since a riviis isn't needed lchathcila,and for cleanliness . However, for ruach raah it wouldn't work. Rav Rimon has an interesting teshuva (written during Covid times ),that if one is worried about germs they can wash their hands,make the bracha and dry them ,and then use hand sanitizer or wash with soap water and dry again...

Comment: @sam feel free to write this as a full answer